# html - scrollbar jump by itself

Tags: html, scrollbar

I'm experiencing this weird problem which my scrollbar jumps by itself to somewhere that I don't want it to.

I have a table with scrollbar inside this page, if the user have a smaller screen, the page automatically adds a scrollbar. If I scroll down to the bottom of the table and click on it, the scrollbar of the page jumps up so I can no longer see the thing I clicked. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a page where this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things that can be causing this.

- You clicked on a hyperlink with a href of "#", which will cause most browsers to scroll to the top of the page,
- There's possibly a CSS `:focus` or `:active` rule somewhere being triggered that causes the height of the page to change
- There's a javascript onclick event firing and changing the page
- ...or possibly something else entirely.

Have you tried in different browsers? It could be a bug in the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the object causing the problem is not an `<a href='#'><div onclick='yourJavaScriptFunction()'>...</div></a>` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a meta refresh tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

I have seen these cause similar issues on safari, post a link to the page and you will find getting a solution much easier.

Answer (score -2):

My scrollbar jumps when I hit Page Up or Page Down.  Also, my laptop trackpad can cause odd mouse behavior if I bounce my thumb against it.

And when I poured a large Latte into my keyboard, I had problems, then.  But then the whole computer stopped working about an hour later.